# Threaded base class C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I want to do  some threaded base class. I wrote the code, that I think should work, it compiles and runs but it doesn't display nothing. I think, the problem is in a callback, but I can be wrong. So, what is wrong in my code?

```
class ThreadedBase
{
public:
    ThreadedBase(bool start = false) : m_running(false) {
        if (start)
            this->start();
    }
    virtual ~ThreadedBase() {
        m_running = false;
        m_thread.join();
    }

    bool start(){
        if (m_running) {
            return false;
        };
        m_thread = std::thread(&ThreadedBase::run, this);
        m_running = true;
        return true;
    };

    bool stop(){
        if (!m_running) {
            return false;
        };
        m_running = false;
        return true;
    };

protected:
    virtual void threadedBlock() = 0;

    void run() {
        while (m_running) {
            threadedBlock();
        }
    }

private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    bool m_running;
};

class Test : public ThreadedBase
{
public:
    Test(bool start = true) : ThreadedBase(start) {}

    void threadedBlock() {
        std::cout << "Task\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t(true);
    t.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't display anything", do you mean it doesn't display the command prompt (or wherever you run the program) or do you simply mean it doesn't display any text?

Comment: It doesn't display (std::cout << "Task\n";):
Task
Task
....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add:

```
m_running = true;
```

before:

```
m_thread = std::thread(&ThreadedBase::run, this);
```

Comment: Yep, the problem was in this. But now it crashes with "pure virtual function call"

Comment: Try adding the "override" keyword to Test::threadedBlock's declaration to make sure you properly override the function.

Comment: You called  start from base class constructor, derived object does not exist. remove  if (start)  this->start() from base constructor and add it to derived class.

Comment: More precisely, the problem is that "start" uses a virtual function "run" from the base class' constructor.
"start" itself is not a problem, because it is not virtual

Answer (score 1):

You are never flushing the std::cout stream.
Try changing:

```
std::cout << "Task\n";
```

to

```
std::cout << "Task" << std::endl;
```

Or call `std::cout.flush();` somewhere in the thread's code.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a problem :)

Comment: It should/could be a problem, I think. It could work right now on your platform but not work on others